# Assigning user to multiple groups in JIRA

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jira, jira-rest-api

I have a question regarding adding user to groups in Jira using rest api. So, I wrote this code in python and it works just fine. However, if I would like to add this one user to multiple groups, what is the right syntax. I tried a lot of syntax and none of them worked and I also searched online and found none. Would appreciate it if someone helped me. Thank you

```
  headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
    query = {'groupname': 'groupname'} 
    data = '{"name": "name"}'
    response = requests.post('url', headers=headers, params=query, data=data, verify=False, auth=(username, password))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Jira REST API endpoints do not support adding multiple groups to a user in a single request (at least as of now).

You should add groups to a user one by one using the following endpoints:

- Jira Server/DC: POST /rest/api/2/group/user
- Jira Cloud:     POST /rest/api/3/group/user

Thanks,
Oleh